# Efficient way to pass all valid props to child?

Tags: reactjs

**See example at bottom!**

**It lets me exclude:**

1. `type='checkbox'`
2. `className={CSS.checkbox + ' ' + CSS.mySpecialCheckbox}`

**and it allows the flexibility to:**

1. pool common styles in `checkbox.sass`
2. pull unique styles from the parent class' associated `.sass` file, if it doesn't exist in the common pool (`CSS['randomClass']` will fail, but the string was transpiled by parent's `CSS` reference, and will apply those styles)

---

**The question is this -- sometimes we don't want to automagically forward all props into the `<input>` element, since React throws a warning about putting random attributes on a DOM element**

Is there any tricky way to exclude certain props from getting passed on?

I'm thinking a spread operator with all applicable React eventHandlers + input attributes, but a more reasonable solution would be to contain all 'Real React/DOM attributes' in one random attribute, which I would prefer not to do.

I know this is confusing, but help is much appreciated.

Thanks

---

```
import React from 'react'
import CSS from '../css/checkbox.sass'

export default class Checkbox extends React.Component {
  render () {
    const className = (
      (CSS.checkbox) + ' ' +
      (CSS[this.props.className] || '') + ' ' +
      (this.props.className || '')
    );

    return (
      <input {...this.props} type='checkbox' className={className} />
    );
  }
}
```

---

```
<Checkbox className='circle' onClick={this.doSomething}>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I'm an idiot, I just realized the answer

The solution is to copy `this.props` then simply `delete` the ones that you know aren't applicable, but that you want to consume during the render phase

Similar to how I'm overriding `className=` after it would already have been declared, but instead of `asdfBlahBlah=''` which isn't valid, I just have to do:

```
let props = Object.assign({}, this.props);
delete props.asdfBlahBlah

return (<input {...props} type='checkbox' className={className}>)
```